I cannot figure out how to decode a csv using cppflow
I am attempting to convert a Python Tensorflow model to C++ using cppflow. While trying to use their cppflow::decode_c_s_v function they have provided, I encountered a zsh: segmentation fault error once my code compiled.
My system architecture is a Mac M2, and current code will be shown below. I am probably just calling the function wrong, but I am unsure what is incorrect, so any help would be appreciated. I have tried to adjust the datatypes and values input into the function, but that results in different errors.
Code:
#include <cppflow/raw_ops.h>
#include <cppflow/tensor.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <cppflow/cppflow.h>
#include <cppflow/raw_ops.h>

class TensorflowModel
{
    public:
        int load_data(std::string data_path);
};

int TensorflowModel::load_data(std::string data_path)
{
    cppflow::tensor raw_csv = cppflow::read_file(data_path);
    cppflow::decode_c_s_v(raw_csv, std::vector<cppflow::tensor> {cppflow::tensor(), cppflow::tensor(), cppflow::tensor(), cppflow::tensor()}, std::vector<cppflow::datatype>{cppflow::datatype::TF_FLOAT}, std::vector<int64_t>{0,1,2,3});
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    // Open the CSV file
    TensorflowModel modelClass;
    int error_code = modelClass.load_data("/Users/mistera2u/Documents/CPP_Tensorflow/iris.csv");
    return 0;
}

Iris.csv:
5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.9,3.0,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.7,3.2,1.3,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.6,3.1,1.5,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.0,3.6,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.4,3.9,1.7,0.4,Iris-setosa
4.6,3.4,1.4,0.3,Iris-setosa
5.0,3.4,1.5,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.4,2.9,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.9,3.1,1.5,0.1,Iris-setosa
5.4,3.7,1.5,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.8,3.4,1.6,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.8,3.0,1.4,0.1,Iris-setosa
4.3,3.0,1.1,0.1,Iris-setosa
5.8,4.0,1.2,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.7,4.4,1.5,0.4,Iris-setosa
5.4,3.9,1.3,0.4,Iris-setosa
5.1,3.5,1.4,0.3,Iris-setosa
5.7,3.8,1.7,0.3,Iris-setosa
5.1,3.8,1.5,0.3,Iris-setosa
5.4,3.4,1.7,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.1,3.7,1.5,0.4,Iris-setosa
4.6,3.6,1.0,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.1,3.3,1.7,0.5,Iris-setosa
4.8,3.4,1.9,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.0,3.0,1.6,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.0,3.4,1.6,0.4,Iris-setosa
5.2,3.5,1.5,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.2,3.4,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.7,3.2,1.6,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.8,3.1,1.6,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.4,3.4,1.5,0.4,Iris-setosa
5.2,4.1,1.5,0.1,Iris-setosa
5.5,4.2,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.9,3.1,1.5,0.1,Iris-setosa
5.0,3.2,1.2,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.5,3.5,1.3,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.9,3.1,1.5,0.1,Iris-setosa
4.4,3.0,1.3,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.1,3.4,1.5,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.0,3.5,1.3,0.3,Iris-setosa
4.5,2.3,1.3,0.3,Iris-setosa
4.4,3.2,1.3,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.0,3.5,1.6,0.6,Iris-setosa
5.1,3.8,1.9,0.4,Iris-setosa
4.8,3.0,1.4,0.3,Iris-setosa
5.1,3.8,1.6,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.6,3.2,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.3,3.7,1.5,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.0,3.3,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
7.0,3.2,4.7,1.4,Iris-versicolor
6.4,3.2,4.5,1.5,Iris-versicolor
6.9,3.1,4.9,1.5,Iris-versicolor
5.5,2.3,4.0,1.3,Iris-versicolor
6.5,2.8,4.6,1.5,Iris-versicolor
5.7,2.8,4.5,1.3,Iris-versicolor
6.3,3.3,4.7,1.6,Iris-versicolor
4.9,2.4,3.3,1.0,Iris-versicolor
6.6,2.9,4.6,1.3,Iris-versicolor
5.2,2.7,3.9,1.4,Iris-versicolor
5.0,2.0,3.5,1.0,Iris-versicolor
5.9,3.0,4.2,1.5,Iris-versicolor
6.0,2.2,4.0,1.0,Iris-versicolor
6.1,2.9,4.7,1.4,Iris-versicolor
5.6,2.9,3.6,1.3,Iris-versicolor
6.7,3.1,4.4,1.4,Iris-versicolor
5.6,3.0,4.5,1.5,Iris-versicolor
5.8,2.7,4.1,1.0,Iris-versicolor
6.2,2.2,4.5,1.5,Iris-versicolor
5.6,2.5,3.9,1.1,Iris-versicolor
5.9,3.2,4.8,1.8,Iris-versicolor
6.1,2.8,4.0,1.3,Iris-versicolor
6.3,2.5,4.9,1.5,Iris-versicolor
6.1,2.8,4.7,1.2,Iris-versicolor
6.4,2.9,4.3,1.3,Iris-versicolor
6.6,3.0,4.4,1.4,Iris-versicolor
6.8,2.8,4.8,1.4,Iris-versicolor
6.7,3.0,5.0,1.7,Iris-versicolor
6.0,2.9,4.5,1.5,Iris-versicolor
5.7,2.6,3.5,1.0,Iris-versicolor
5.5,2.4,3.8,1.1,Iris-versicolor
5.5,2.4,3.7,1.0,Iris-versicolor
5.8,2.7,3.9,1.2,Iris-versicolor
6.0,2.7,5.1,1.6,Iris-versicolor
5.4,3.0,4.5,1.5,Iris-versicolor
6.0,3.4,4.5,1.6,Iris-versicolor
6.7,3.1,4.7,1.5,Iris-versicolor
6.3,2.3,4.4,1.3,Iris-versicolor
5.6,3.0,4.1,1.3,Iris-versicolor
5.5,2.5,4.0,1.3,Iris-versicolor
5.5,2.6,4.4,1.2,Iris-versicolor
6.1,3.0,4.6,1.4,Iris-versicolor
5.8,2.6,4.0,1.2,Iris-versicolor
5.0,2.3,3.3,1.0,Iris-versicolor
5.6,2.7,4.2,1.3,Iris-versicolor
5.7,3.0,4.2,1.2,Iris-versicolor
5.7,2.9,4.2,1.3,Iris-versicolor
6.2,2.9,4.3,1.3,Iris-versicolor
5.1,2.5,3.0,1.1,Iris-versicolor
5.7,2.8,4.1,1.3,Iris-versicolor
6.3,3.3,6.0,2.5,Iris-virginica
5.8,2.7,5.1,1.9,Iris-virginica
7.1,3.0,5.9,2.1,Iris-virginica
6.3,2.9,5.6,1.8,Iris-virginica
6.5,3.0,5.8,2.2,Iris-virginica
7.6,3.0,6.6,2.1,Iris-virginica
4.9,2.5,4.5,1.7,Iris-virginica
7.3,2.9,6.3,1.8,Iris-virginica
6.7,2.5,5.8,1.8,Iris-virginica
7.2,3.6,6.1,2.5,Iris-virginica
6.5,3.2,5.1,2.0,Iris-virginica
6.4,2.7,5.3,1.9,Iris-virginica
6.8,3.0,5.5,2.1,Iris-virginica
5.7,2.5,5.0,2.0,Iris-virginica
5.8,2.8,5.1,2.4,Iris-virginica
6.4,3.2,5.3,2.3,Iris-virginica
6.5,3.0,5.5,1.8,Iris-virginica
7.7,3.8,6.7,2.2,Iris-virginica
7.7,2.6,6.9,2.3,Iris-virginica
6.0,2.2,5.0,1.5,Iris-virginica
6.9,3.2,5.7,2.3,Iris-virginica
5.6,2.8,4.9,2.0,Iris-virginica
7.7,2.8,6.7,2.0,Iris-virginica
6.3,2.7,4.9,1.8,Iris-virginica
6.7,3.3,5.7,2.1,Iris-virginica
7.2,3.2,6.0,1.8,Iris-virginica
6.2,2.8,4.8,1.8,Iris-virginica
6.1,3.0,4.9,1.8,Iris-virginica
6.4,2.8,5.6,2.1,Iris-virginica
7.2,3.0,5.8,1.6,Iris-virginica
7.4,2.8,6.1,1.9,Iris-virginica
7.9,3.8,6.4,2.0,Iris-virginica
6.4,2.8,5.6,2.2,Iris-virginica
6.3,2.8,5.1,1.5,Iris-virginica
6.1,2.6,5.6,1.4,Iris-virginica
7.7,3.0,6.1,2.3,Iris-virginica
6.3,3.4,5.6,2.4,Iris-virginica
6.4,3.1,5.5,1.8,Iris-virginica
6.0,3.0,4.8,1.8,Iris-virginica
6.9,3.1,5.4,2.1,Iris-virginica
6.7,3.1,5.6,2.4,Iris-virginica
6.9,3.1,5.1,2.3,Iris-virginica
5.8,2.7,5.1,1.9,Iris-virginica
6.8,3.2,5.9,2.3,Iris-virginica
6.7,3.3,5.7,2.5,Iris-virginica
6.7,3.0,5.2,2.3,Iris-virginica
6.3,2.5,5.0,1.9,Iris-virginica
6.5,3.0,5.2,2.0,Iris-virginica
6.2,3.4,5.4,2.3,Iris-virginica
5.9,3.0,5.1,1.8,Iris-virginica


Run the program under a debugger to help pinpoint the segfault. Then gather information about what happened by using the debugger to investigate the crash site (inspect the callstack, check the values of the variables in use, etc...). If you see something unusual, trace it back to the source. You'll probably find the answer yourself by doing this, but if not, you can write a very well-targeted question that'll be answered within minutes.
